# What is wrong with 'echo 'a\\b' | grep "\\"'

Tags: linux, bash, grep

When I am running this

```
echo 'a\\b' | grep '\\'
```

it correctly identifies the backslashes

but when I used the double quotes

```
echo 'a\\b' | grep "\\"
```

It is not running and it is returning a trailing backlash error, I can't figure out why that happens. It should work exactly similar to single quotes as I have escaped the backslashes.

Answer (score 4):

When using double quotes the `\\` gets evaluated into `\`. Single quotes leaves things as-is. Do an `echo "\\"` to see what I mean.

Comment: echo needs -e to interpret the slash as an escape doesnt it?

Comment: the shell interprets \\ in double quotes. `echo -e '\\'` results in the same as `echo "\\"`.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple places where backslash escapes can be processed:

- In your shell: This happens when you use double quotes and not single quotes. Note that this is a very limited processing and escapes like `"\n"` will not work. This means when you do `echo "a\\b"` echo will get `a\b` as first argument while when you're executing `echo 'a\\b'` echo will get `a\\b` as first argument.
- In the program you're calling: `grep` will parse the input as POSIX regular expression which has its own set of escapes. `echo` may or may not handle escape codes by default. My `/bin/echo` will not process escape codes by default, my `bash` bulitin `echo` also won't but my `zsh` builtin `echo` will. If a certain behaviour is wanted this can be specified by `-e` to enable escapes or by `-E` to disable escapes.

So if you're calling `grep "\\"` the shell will process the `\\` escape sequence and pass `\` to grep which will try to parse that as a regular expression and correclty complains about a trailing backslash.

So when you use double quotes you have to double escape everything resulting in the rather clumsy `echo 'a\\b' | grep "\\\\"`.

To get the least amount of escaping you can use `echo 'a\\b' | grep '\\'` or even `echo 'a\\b' | grep -F '\'`, where the `-F` flag tells grep to interpret the pattern as verbatim string and not as a regular expression. If you happen to have an `echo` that processes escapes by default (this will result in `echo 'a\\b'` printing `a\b`) you also need to add `-E` to the `echo` command.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, What is the use of -E in echo, single quotes ignore all of the meta-charters special meaning anyway?

Comment: I partially misinterpreted your question since my `echo` processes escapes by default and assumed you wanted to print only one backslash as you were grepping for only one. The `echo` program itself doesn't know whether you used single or double quotes.

Comment: I meant -E s redundant when the value to be printed is in single quotes'..'

Comment: The `-E` option has nothing to do with the kind of quotes used. In your case the `-E` option will do nothing at all since it is the default for the `echo` command (and I was only confused because it is not in `zsh`). For example `echo -E "\\a"` will print `\a` as the `-E` cannot stop the shell from processing the escape in double quotes. The other way around `echo -e '\\a'` will also print `\a` as the single quotes will not stop `echo` from processing the escape. I hope this clarifies the behaviour.

Comment: yes it does, thanks. I never tried -e with '' for obvious reasons. I am confused enough :D

Answer (score 1):

grep does a bit of basic regular expression matching.

When in double quotes, the shell parses `\\`, so `\\` will resolve to a single backslash as a parameter.

Additionally, grep does a bit of basic regular expression matching, so to match a single backslash you need to pass two backslashes to grep.

So by calling `grep "\\"` you actually get `grep \`, which does not parse as a regular expression, therefore makes grep fail.

To correctly match only double backslashes, do `grep -F '\\'` (which means fixed string matching instead of regex), `grep '\\\\'` or `grep "\\\\\\\\"`.